# Java Smack XMPP view server response

Tags: java, xmpp, smack, facebook-chat

Hey how can i display every response from the xmpp server?

I try to send messages but a lot of them get lost on the way so i want to check the response of the server. I am using smack 3.3.1 sending to the facebook xmpp port.

DeliveryReceiptManager and/or MessageEventManager wont show anything so i would like to see everything the server is responding!

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com",5222);
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);     
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

        try {
            //ESTA LINEA HACE QUE NO DE TIMEOUT
            SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(15000);
            XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
            SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.class);
            SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", 0);
            connection.connect();
            String apiKey = "1234567";
            String accessToken = "";
            connection.login(apiKey, accessToken);

        }catch (XMPPException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            DeliveryReceiptManager deliveryReceiptManager = DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            deliveryReceiptManager.addReceiptReceivedListener(new ReceiptReceivedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiptReceived(String s, String s2, String s3) {
                    System.out.println("REVEIVED RESPONCE");
                    System.out.println(s);
                    System.out.println(s2);
                    System.out.println(s3);
                }
            });
            Chat chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat("1234567890@chat.facebook.com", new MessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                    if(message.getType() == Message.Type.chat)
                        System.out.println(chat.getParticipant() + " says: " + message.getBody());
                }
            });
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.setSubject("Invite");
            msg.setBody("blablabla");
            DeliveryReceiptManager.addDeliveryReceiptRequest(msg);
            //MessageEventManager.addNotificationsRequests(msg, true, true, true, true);

            chat.sendMessage(msg);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }catch (XMPPException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;

Comment: Then the debug window should be open with all activity (both ways) being displayed.  Is that not coming up?

Comment: No there is nothing being displayed. Should there be additional debug output? Thanks!

Comment: which IDE are you using?